# Compile generates non-tensor object warning for this simple function

Tags: compile, precision-and-accuracy

`Compile` generates the following error (CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.) upon execution of this simple function `fn1[pt, opentri]` and how to resolve the issue? Note that the function without `Compile` works fine.

```
ClearAll[fn1];
Block[{temp, firstelem},
 fn1 = Compile[{{sourcept, _Real, 1}, {ls, _Real, 3}},
   (firstelem = #[[1]];
      If[Chop[firstelem - sourcept, 10^-8] == {0., 0., 0.},
       #,
       RotateLeft[#, First[Position[#, sourcept]] - 1]]) & /@ ls
   ,
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ]
 ]
```

where `` pt = {-0.01645930097046247042591460285620996729`8.,0.4325228008917327838`8.,0.4127145715152158445`8.}; ``
and the second argument is:

```
opentri = {{{0.1575639491896651811`8., 0.8930167660947179176`8., 
     0.4037575264860177038`8.}, \
{-0.01645930097046247042591460285620996729`8., 
     0.4325228008917327838`8., 
     0.4127145715152158445`8.}, {0.4333460612444884896`8., 
     0.4168931919652226759`8., 
     0.4581710563101135114`8.}}, \
{{-0.01645930097046247042591460285620996729`8., 
     0.4325228008917327838`8., 
     0.4127145715152158445`8.}, {0.1437933000929649541`8., 
     0.02310394547537703360817751274680631468`8., 
     0.5810140906075491607`8.}, {0.4333460612444884896`8., 
     0.4168931919652226759`8., 
     0.4581710563101135114`8.}}, {{0.1437933000929639549`8., 
     0.02310394547537703360817751274680631468`8., 
     0.5810140906075491607`8.}, \
{-0.01645930097046247042591460285620996729`8., 
     0.4325228008917327838`8., 
     0.4127145715152158445`8.}, {-0.2408181610124800476`8., 
     0.02828371955366073067783538874664372997`8., 
     0.4989092540607453774`8.}}, \
{{-0.01645930097046247042591460285620996729`8., 
     0.4325228008917327838`8., 
     0.4127145715152158445`8.}, {-0.4529706655450617403`8., 
     0.4675525533083570995`8., 
     0.4698128950000378667`8.}, {-0.2408181610124800476`8., 
     0.02828371955366073067783538874664372997`8., 
     0.4989092540607453774`8.}}, {{-0.4529706655450614072`8., 
     0.4675525533083570995`8., 
     0.4698128950000378667`8.}, \
{-0.0164593009704621373590072153092478402`8., 
     0.4325228008917327838`8., 
     0.4127145715152158445`8.}, {-0.2248024098901401924`8., 
     0.8607932575117263063`8., 
     0.4368553172652774874`8.}}, \
{{-0.0164593009704621373590072153092478402`8., 
     0.4325228008917327838`8., 
     0.4127145715152158445`8.}, {0.1575639491896651811`8., 
     0.8930167660947179176`8., 
     0.4037575264860177038`8.}, {-0.2248024098901401924`8., 
     0.8607932575117263063`8., 0.4368553172652774874`8.}}};
```

Comment: `Block` should be inside `Compile`. This isn't the root of problem, of course.

Comment: @xzczd thanks. any idea what maybe going wrong? the function works without Compile, albeit each subfunction is compilable

Comment: Interesting. I can boil down the problem to the following: `posfunc = Compile[{{lsmember, _Real, 2}, {pt, _Real, 1}}, Position[lsmember, pt]];
posfunc[opentri[[-2]], pt]` But I'm not sure why.

Comment: Oh, I see, the precision of your data is `8`, but the only allowed precision in `Compile` is `MachinePrecision`, when `opentri` and `pt` are fed into `fn1`, the data actually changes, so `Position` fails.

Comment: @xzczd thanks. posted the modified function below. this one does not issue the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Let me extend my comments to an answer. The problem can be boiled down to the following:

```
posfunc = 
  Compile[{{lsmember, _Real, 2}, {pt, _Real, 1}}, Position[lsmember, pt]];
posfunc[opentri[[-2]], pt]
(* {} *)
```

while

```
Position[opentri[[-2]], pt]
(* {{2}} *)
```

Why? Because the precision of the inputs is `8`, but the only allowed precision for approximate number in `Compile` is `MachinePrecision`, when `opentri` and `pt` are fed into `fn1`, the data actually changes, so `Position` fails in `Compile`. (BTW it's a bit surprising to me that `Position` takes precision into account, I dimly thought things like `` Position[{1.000001`2}, 1.000002`2] `` should output `{}`! )

So, how to fix the code? Here's my solution, which makes use of quicksort:

```
cf = 
 Compile[{{pt, _Real, 1}, {ls, _Real, 3}}, 
  RotateLeft[#, Ordering[#\[Transpose] - pt // Transpose // Abs, 1] - 1] & /@ ls];

rst = cf[pt, opentri]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0000203921, Null} *)

(* fn1 from Ali's answer: *)
rst2 = fn1[pt, opentri]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0000371906, Null} *)

rst == rst2
(* True *)
```

Comment: Will accept yours as the answer ! thanks :)

Comment: @Ali Feel free to wait for a while for better answers :)

Answer (score 1):

partly based on xzczd's suggestion we can rewrite the function

```
fn1 = Compile[{{sourcept, _Real, 1}, {ls, _Real, 3}},
  Block[{temp, firstelem, vec, pos = 0},
   (vec = #;
      firstelem = Compile`GetElement[vec, 1];
      If[Chop[firstelem - sourcept, 10^-8] == {0., 0., 0.},
       vec,
       Which[
        Chop[Compile`GetElement[vec,2] - sourcept, 10^-8] == {0.,0.,0.},
        pos = 2,
        Chop[Compile`GetElement[vec,3] - sourcept, 10^-8] == {0.,0.,0.},
        pos = 3
        ];
       RotateLeft[vec, pos - 1]
       ]) & /@ ls
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
    "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```